# Why do Star Wars B2 Battle Droids only use one arm?

Tags: star-wars

Whenever I see a B2 battle droid fighting, they are always using only their right arm.  On the Star Wars Wiki, it states that the droids are equipped with dual laser cannons on their right forearm, but in the Clone Wars and in many pictures of B2 battle droids, they appear to have another laser cannon on their second arm.  In one episode of the Clone Wars, a Jedi cuts off the right arm of a B2 battle droid and the droid attempts to lock its left arm into firing position.  Also, in another episode, a droid popper was tossed at a B2's feet and the droid proceeded to shoot at the grenade with BOTH of its arms.  Why don't the B2 battle droids attack with both of their arms, regardless of whether or not their left arm is a blaster or some other secondary weapon?

This is a link to a picture of a battle droid seen in the first episode of season one of the Clone Wars.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unidentified_B2_super_battle_droid

EDIT:

I'm not sure if there even is a correct answer, but my only thought was that the battle droids didn't have enough power in their system to function as well as fire multiple blasters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reasons I can think of:

**Power:** As the OP mentioned, there is a good chance of there being a limited power source, and it is much more efficient to accurately fire a single gun, rather than Rambo the sucker.

**Computing Speed:** Assuming you actually want to attempt to hit stuff (unlike our friend Rambo) you need to *aim* your guns.  Now for a human, a dual wield aim is not all that hard.  JK, I'll point out my scapegoat Rambo again.  To actually hit something akimbo fire is rather hard (I've shot guns before, even with a .22 pistol, it's hard to dual wield).  And as we can see in the lovely picture, arm cannons lack sights.  So if you wanted to actually be shooting at anything, advanced ballistic calculations need to occur (even with just one arm).  This could account for the dual firing cases we see.  They say "Screw it with accuracy, we need to pump as much lead [or equivalent] into this sucker and forgo the calculations.

**Kick:** This is highly unlikely as the answer as the cannons appear to have built-in recoil compensators so as to limit kick on an already basically kick-less weapon.  But the theory is that firing both weapons (even in asynchronous fire patterns) would through the battle droid off balance.

Comment: This is pure conjecture, there is absolutely no proof submitted but a guess by you.-1.